# How do you format the JSON body for a Transfer Receipt REST web services call?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use the Contract based web services to retrieve Transfer Receipts.  I've extended the endpoint for PurchaseReceipt (Endpoint name is POTransfer) to add TransferOrderNbr,  TransferType, and TransferShipmentNbr (The endpoint object is PurchaseReceiptEx).  The Call I'm using works for 2018 R1, but in a site that's been upgraded to 2021 R1, Using Postman, the PUT call to the Endpoint returns errors.

[image]

Here is the call:

```
https://<base URL>/entity/POTransfer/17.200.001/PurchaseReceiptEx?Expand=Details
```

And here is the JSON payload / body I'm using:

```
{
"Type": {
    "value": "Transfer Receipt"
},
"Warehouse": {
    "value": "SOV-3RD"
},
"Details": [
    {
        "Location": {
            "value": "QC41"
        },
        "TransferOrderNbr": {
            "value": "SO00011242"
        },
        "TransferOrderType": {
            "value": "TR"
        },
        "TransferShipmentNbr": {
            "value": "011736"
        }
    }
]
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
"exceptionMessage": "PurchaseReceipt.VendorID: 'Vendor' cannot be empty.\n'VendorID' cannot be empty.\nVendorID: 'VendorID' cannot be empty.",
```

So, I guess the bottom line is - how do I format the body for this call without getting errors?

Comment: I don't work via web services, so I don't have a specific answer.  However, it seems like at Summit last year I heard the older endpoint versions were being deprecated.  By chance, does it work with a newer endpoint version?  If memory serves, you should be on 18.xxx or newer.  The upgrade cycle tries to keep you within the last 2 years, and version 17 will be 5 years old this year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with this a bit and trying all my tricks, I believe this might just be an error with the 17.200.001 endpoint. I tried this with 17.200.001, 18.200.001 and 20.200.001 endpoint versions and your call format worked with both 18.200.001 and 20.200.001. Along with what Brian said, probably best to just upgrade.

Comment: I also had problems with this transaction a couple of years ago using endpoint version 17.200.001 and it was resolved with 18.200.001.